# Extract MPEG7 Visual Descriptors with PHP

Tags: php, mpeg

I'm a student. I need some descriptors of MPEG7 in PHP which will be used for my research. The descriptors are dominant color, color layout, color structure, scalable color, edge histogram and homogeneous texture. Do you know where can I find PHP source code / documentation for some of these these descriptors?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should able to extract frames of video with PHP-FFMpeg: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Below is the code they use as an example to extract a frame:

```
    $frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(42));
    $frame->save('image.jpg');
```

After doing that you can grab the dominant color and color palette with Color Thief PHP: https://github.com/ksubileau/color-thief-php

Image histogram can be obtained with Imagick.

I am unsure of the rest because of my lack of knowledge about image manipulation.

Comment: Thankyou Kevin for your help. I'll try first.
But how if i want extract an image? I can skip to second step? Using Color Thief PHP ?

Comment: Yes. If you only want to extract the image, then you can only do the first step.